# ¿How to use microphone in a Bluetooth headset?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone

I am using various headsets (headset) connected under BT and none of them works with Ubuntu :( The device pairs with BT, is visible in the sound outputs, unfortunately it does not appear among the microphones.

Have any of you managed to fire up a headset under Ubuntu so that the microphone works as well? It's a strange thing, because occasionally on the Internet such a problem appears, but the solution proposed there (with the replacement of the sound daemon) does not cause any change in my case.

I've tried it for a couple of years, on Xubuntu with XFCE, now on Ubuntu with Gnome, and it continues to go kaput.

Comment: Is the audio profile for the headphones A2DP or HSP/HFP?

Comment: @Jeremy31 How to check it? All headphones works good with android and windows It's JBL, it's Sennheiser and something from Lidl. And muvo play speaker (with microphone). I use them all with android.

Comment: It should be shown in Ubuntu Sound Settings for the headset